# In what (free) software can I draw bodies in a 3D coordinate system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, software, drawings

[image]

I'm looking for a software in which I can make images of this kind.

Comment: Yes I tried but it's not so easy

Comment: Which have you found so others don’t re-offer packages you have already discarded?

Comment: I have found none, only those that draw dots and planes but none that draw bodies like in the picture

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, Linux and Mac, [Solvespace](http://solvespace.com/index.pl) will allow one to create three dimensional objects in a parametric as well as free-form manner.

[image: solvespace example image]

Text and dimensions are part of the program's features. The web site provides tutorials and other useful reference material.

If you did not have the requirement for dimensions, [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) would have been a good choice. There may be a library for OpenSCAD which supports dimensioning, but I doubt the arrows would be part of that option.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [FreeCAD](https://www.freecadweb.org/), it's a 3D modelling software. It's more geared towards making a 3D assembly than making drawings though.

Another option is [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) which is a vector graphics program.

Comment: Inkscape is the correct answer here. There’s no requirement to make an actual 3D model for diagrams this simple, but effortless vector output is definitely what’s key